# How to mod_rewrite so all paths are proxied except base path, using .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write some proxing rewrite rules using mod_rewrite for my site but cant get it to work. Please help out, mod_rewrite experts.

I need to proxy all sub-paths to an external server while preserving the URI, but I dont want to rewrite the base path /.

I do not know the sub path's name and I want it to be treated like a wildcard 
   /*[/*[/*...]]

- www.domain.com/ -> www.domain.com/index.php
- www.domain.com/xxx/ -> www.external-server.com/xxx/
- www.domain.com/xxx/yyy/ -> www.external-server.com/xxx/yyy/
- www.domain.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/ -> www.external-server.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/

I can easily proxy calls on all URI's like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.external-server.com/$1 [P,QSA]
```

Anyone got an idea about a working set of rules and cond's supporting my use case?

Thanks in advance!// 
   Edsh

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, something like this should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/index.php [L,P,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUESTURI} !^/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.external-server.com/$1 [P,QSA]
```

Comment: Thx Petey! But it ends up in a loop, giving HTTP 400 Bad Request. Any idea?

Comment: With your code: 
http://www.domain.com/ -> bad request
http://www.domain.com/xxx/ -> bad request
http://www.domain.com/index.php -> works

Comment: Typo in the RewriteCond on the second condition btw. Should be %{REQUEST_URI}. Try removing the whole first condition and rule as well.

Comment: Now it works as my described use-case. I tweaked your config a bit, Petey! I guess the problem was due to using the same domain on the base URI rewrite. I changed [L, P, QSA] to [L, R, QSA]

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Good stuff.